# Finding out what privilege is required to run a given MongoDB command

Tags: mongodb

I'm running `replSetReconfig` on the primary of a replica set and get this error:

> not authorized on admin to execute command replSetReconfig

It's [not documented](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/DOCS-12762) what privilege this command requires, so the general question is: How can I determine the privilege required to run a given MongoDB command, so that I can run the corresponding `db.grantRolesToUser()` command and grant the user the necessary privilege?

Answer (score 0):

One solution is to look through the [built-in roles](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/built-in-roles/) page for the operation you want to perform.

In this case, `clusterManager` provides the `replSetConfigure` action.